# Canvas Orientation Change Scaling Android

Tags: android, canvas, drawing, orientation, scaling

I'm developing an painting app at the moment for the first time. I can draw and such things.
But everytime the orientation changes, everything is lost. How can i fix this? I have been searching on the internet for solution but dont seem to find one. I know it has to to with the onSizeChanged event from the view class. I have overriden that event and changed a lot to make it work with the orientation change but i cant get it to work.
Here is the code from the onSizeChanged event:

```
private Canvas drawCanvas;
private Bitmap canvasBitmap;

@Override
protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
    //View given size
    super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);
    canvasBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(w, h, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    drawCanvas = new Canvas(canvasBitmap);
}
```

I have already tryed android:configChanges. But it doesnt seem to work.

Comment: In your manifest, with the associated Activity add `android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"` but understand this is a hacked fix and you would likely be better off creating a parcelable class that handles your drawings during onSavedInstanceState

Comment: It is still getting erased when i changed the orientation. I had added that line before but it doesnt seem to work.

Comment: And you made sure to include screenSize (required with API 13+ I believe).

Comment: Where do I need to add screenSize? EDIT: I used the line that zgc7009 said. WIth the screenSize added to it.

Comment: If your line was `android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"` without the `|screenSize` portion (which wasn't required until recently) it wouldn't work. A lot of examples don't include that part since they are older so wanted to make sure you included it.

Comment: I had added the |screenSize part. But it doesnt seem to work. It does not need to be in the application category or intent category?

Comment: Na just needs to be attached to the associated activity. Never had that one not work before. Add the line to your manifest that I told you to, oh and make sure to delete your onSizeChanged method as you don't want to mess with that

Comment: @zgc7009 But if i delete that method. How do i recreate my canvas and scale it again?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/52413/discussion-between-markieo-and-zgc7009)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have found an solution for this problem. Everytime the screen orientation changed the event was being called. So the bitmap was recreated everytime. I have fixed this by scaling the bitmap before recreation and then setting it as new bitmap. This way it is automatticly scaled and nothing is lost.
This is the full code now:

```
private Canvas drawCanvas;
private Bitmap canvasBitmap;

@Override
protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
    //View given size
    super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);
    if(canvasBitmap == null){
        canvasBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(w, h, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    }else{
        Bitmap temporary = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(canvasBitmap, w, h, true);
        canvasBitmap = temporary;
    }
    drawCanvas = new Canvas(canvasBitmap);
}
```